# Not Start Hibernate in each Test (Java Spring)

Tags: java, spring

I have some tests for my project, where not database connection is needed. Sometimes I have no Database-Connection, is it possible to not start database connection while testing to avoid the errors? The error is not a problem, the program will proceed but `2021-05-19 18:11:53.610  INFO 56965 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...` takes very much time every run.

Comment: yes it is, if DB is part of some `@Configuration` you could have a `@ConditionalOnPorperty` on it - and simply disable that it your tests

Comment: currently Im not using db as part of some configuration. I configure it in the properties file.

Comment: Do those tests require Spring at all? Perhaps they shouldn't be run using `SpringRunner`

Comment: Some of them need some other Spring dependencies

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is running tests using Spring. Generally this approach is taken for so-called integration testing. This means that Spring is booted up and usually runs with an in memory database (H2). Classes containing these tests have the @SpringBootTest annotation.

If you are running tests and you do not want all of Spring to launch (there is a lot more overhead than just connecting to the database) you may want to consider running your tests using JUnit. This approach is generally used in conjunction with a mocking framework and can be used to perform unit testing. JUnit tests have the @Test annotation above them.

Comment: I'm using the SpringBootTestand Test annotation. The H2 is a great idea, that will do it, thanks!